# Upgrading from MVC Preview 3 to Beta/RC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have a web app that is using MVC Preview 3. I'm new to the project and relatively new to ASP.NET MVC itself - soon we will be looking to upgrade to either the Beta or RC version.

1. Are there any major difference between preview 3 and Beta version that would require extensive refactoring?
2. Any "gotchas"?
3. From my understanding the RC will be very close to the current Beta... does anyone have a view on this?

Any advice apprecited really.... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were quite a few changes between preview 3 to the beta. IIRC the most pain came between preview 3 - preview 4.

One of the biggest gotchas is some of the functionality in the main dlls got placed into a separate dll because they were not going to be fully supported for the first release.

I suggest you brew a large pot of coffee and go and read everything Phil Haack and Scott Gu wrote around that time.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/16/aspnetmvc-codeplex-preview4.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/07/14/asp-net-mvc-preview-4-release-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

ASP NET MVC - Beta Release Notes has all the details regarding the changes. It is available at the mvc download page.